# How do I create an array in Javascript with different values in each variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, tone.js

Not sure if the question explains it very well, but I want to put these Tone.JS filters in an array. The problem is that they all have different frequency and gain values, and will eventually have different Q values too.

Check out my code below and let me know if this is do-able. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
var noise = new Tone.Noise();

for (counter = 0; counter < 6; counter+=1) {
  var hipass[counter] = new Tone.Filter();
}

for (counter = 0; counter < 6; counter+=1) {
  var lowpass[counter] = new Tone.Filter();
}

var hipass1 = new Tone.Filter(8, "highpass", -12, -77.8);
var hipass2 = new Tone.Filter(16, "highpass", -12, -56.7);
var hipass3 = new Tone.Filter(31.5, "highpass", -12, -39.4);
var hipass4 = new Tone.Filter(63, "highpass", -12, -26.2);
var hipass5 = new Tone.Filter(125, "highpass", -12, -16.1);
var hipass6 = new Tone.Filter(250, "highpass", -12, -8.6);

var lowpass1 = new Tone.Filter(500, "lowpass", -12, -3.2);
var lowpass2 = new Tone.Filter(1000, "lowpass", -12);
var lowpass3 = new Tone.Filter(2000, "lowpass", -12, 1.2);
var lowpass4 = new Tone.Filter(4000, "lowpass", -12, 1.0);
var lowpass5 = new Tone.Filter(8000, "lowpass", -12, -1.1);
var lowpass6 = new Tone.Filter(1200, "lowpass", -12, -6.6);

noise.chain(hipass[counter], lowpass[counter], Tone.Master);
noise.volume = -20;
noise.stop();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript's `.push()` method to append new values to your array:

```
var noise = new Tone.Noise();

var hipass[counter] = new Array();
var lowpass[counter] = new Array();

hipass.push(new Tone.Filter(8, "highpass", -12, -77.8));
hipass.push(new Tone.Filter(16, "highpass", -12, -56.7));
hipass.push(new Tone.Filter(31.5, "highpass", -12, -39.4));
hipass.push(new Tone.Filter(63, "highpass", -12, -26.2));
hipass.push(new Tone.Filter(125, "highpass", -12, -16.1));
hipass.push(new Tone.Filter(250, "highpass", -12, -8.6));

lowpass.push(new Tone.Filter(500, "lowpass", -12, -3.2));
lowpass.push(new Tone.Filter(1000, "lowpass", -12));
lowpass.push(new Tone.Filter(2000, "lowpass", -12, 1.2));
lowpass.push(new Tone.Filter(4000, "lowpass", -12, 1.0));
lowpass.push(new Tone.Filter(8000, "lowpass", -12, -1.1));
lowpass.push(new Tone.Filter(1200, "lowpass", -12, -6.6));

noise.chain(hipass[counter], lowpass[counter], Tone.Master);
noise.volume = -20;
noise.stop();
```